# Unable to render any data on the web page

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm quite new to React and typescript, trying to build simple application which extracts data from API and displays it on web page. After reading some article on the internet and playing around with the code I have managed to fix the errors. But now I'm unable to display any data on the web page. I don't see any errors and I see the data in the console log.

I'm unable to understand why am I getting empty array in the return logic. Can someone advice.

**Code**
**App.tsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ApiProps ,{ DataApiResponse }from '../src/types'


function App() {
  const [Data , setData] = useState<DataApiResponse >({task:[]});  //ApiProps
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  // const [error, setError] = useState(null);
 
  useEffect(()=>{
    setLoading(true)
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=8`)
     .then((response) => response.json())      
     .then((Data)=>{
      setData({ task: Data });
      console.log(Data)
    // setLoading(false)
     })
  },[]);

   if(isLoading) return <p> Loading ...Hello World</p>
   if(!Data.task.length) return <p> No data</p>

   return (
    <div className="contianer">

      <ul>{Data && Data.task?[].map((task:ApiProps)=>( 
        <>
        <li key ={task.id}>{task.id}</li>
        <li>{task.title}</li>
        <li>{task.userId}</li>
        <li>{task.body}</li>
        </>
      )):null }</ul>    
    </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

Types.tsx

```
export default interface ApiProps {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    userId:string,
    body:string
}

export interface DataApiResponse {
    task : ApiProps[]
}
```

**Index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkfSA.png)

Comment: I have updated the code for null check and errors have gone now , but i'm unable to understand why am I getting nulls in the array. below is the updated part of the code                
`**<div className="App">
     <h1>
     Data from API Response
      </h1>
      <ul>{ Data&& Data.task?[].map((dataInt:ApiProps)=>( 
        <>
         <li key ={dataInt.id}>{dataInt.id}</li>
        <li>{dataInt.title}</li>
        </>
      )):null }</ul>
    </div>**`

Comment: Edit the question to reflect the current state of the code

Comment: Updated the code after making changes

Comment: You still didn't implement my answer

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I have implemented the logic you gave, but no luck. I have updated the code for your reference, screenshot of the output

Answer (score 0):

You are removing `task` from your state

Fix:

```
setData({ task: Data })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have updated the code but no luck... the map still has nulls and unable to render any data on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

You are using map in an empty array

`[].map((task:ApiProps)=>(`

change it to use `Data.task` instead

`Data.task.map((task:ApiProps)=>(`

and better to remove the `null` condition

```
      <ul>
        {Data && Data.task && Data.task.map((task: ApiProps) => (
            <>
              <li key={task.id}>{task.id}</li>
              <li>{task.title}</li>
              <li>{task.userId}</li>
              <li>{task.body}</li>
            </>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please make changes to -app.tsx

```
<div className="App">
 <h1>
 Data from API Response
  </h1>
  <ul>{ Data && Data?.task?.map((dataInt:ApiProps)=>( 
    <>
     <li key={dataInt.id}>{dataInt.id}</li>
    <li>{dataInt.title}</li>
    </>
  )) }</ul>
</div>
```

Please check above code and replace with your. If you still facing issue lemme know. I will make more changes in code.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response @varun, I have updated the code but no luck... the map still has nulls and unable to render any data on the web page.